# Sending Devise emails in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I am having problem sending emails in production. Everything works fine in development. Specifically, I just want the app to be able to send the generic email messages from the Devise Gem.

Here's the the code in production.rb

```
   config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'http://ballnow.herokuapp.com' }
   config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
   config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
   config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true

   config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
     address: 'smtp.gmail.com',
     port: 587,
     domain: ENV["GMAIL_DOMAIN"],
     authentication: 'plain',
     enable_starttls_auto: true,
     user_name: ENV["GMAIL_USERNAME"],
     password: ENV["GMAIL_PASSWORD"]
   }
```

I feel like it is something very stupid, but for the past few hours, I can't seem to figure it out. Here is the log from paper trail:

```
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionmailer-4.1.1/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:525:in `deliver_mail' 
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/mail-2.5.4/lib/mail/message.rb:232:in `deliver' 
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/devise-3.2.4/lib/devise/models/authenticatable.rb:173:in `send_devise_notification' 
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/devise-3.2.4/lib/devise/models/confirmable.rb:102:in `send_confirmation_instructions' 
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/devise-3.2.4/lib/devise/models/confirmable.rb:117:in `block in resend_confirmation_instructions' 
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/devise-3.2.4/lib/devise/models/confirmable.rb:211:in `pending_any_confirmation' 
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/devise-3.2.4/lib/devise/models/confirmable.rb:116:in `resend_confirmation_instructions' 
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/devise-3.2.4/lib/devise/models/confirmable.rb:265:in `send_confirmation_instructions' 
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/devise-3.2.4/app/controllers/devise/confirmations_controller.rb:9:in `create' 
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action' 
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action' 
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action' 
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action' 
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:113:in `call' 
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:113:in `call' 
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:149:in `block in halting_and_conditional' 
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `call' 
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `block in halting' 
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `call' 
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:229:in `block in halting' 
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call' 
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting' 
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call' 
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting' 
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call' 
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting' 
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `call' 
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:166:in `block in halting' 
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `call' 
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `run_callbacks' 
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action' 
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action' 
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action' 
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `block in instrument' 
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument' 
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:159:in `instrument' 
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action' 
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action' 
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action' 
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:136:in `process' 
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionview-4.1.1/lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process' 
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch' 
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch' 
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_controller/metal.rb:231:in `block in action' 
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `call' 
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:80:in `dispatch' 
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:48:in `call' 
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:45:in `call' 
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:71:in `block in call' 
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `each' 
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:59:in `call' 
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:676:in `call' 
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.8.1.221/lib/new_relic/rack/error_collector.rb:55:in `call' 
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.8.1.221/lib/new_relic/rack/agent_hooks.rb:32:in `call' 
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/newrelic_rpm-3.8.1.221/lib/new_relic/rack/browser_monitoring.rb:27:in `call' 
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/warden-1.2.3/lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call' 
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/warden-1.2.3/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch' 
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/warden-1.2.3/lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call' 
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/etag.rb:23:in `call' 
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:35:in `call' 
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/head.rb:11:in `call' 
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call' 
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:254:in `call' 
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context' 
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call' 
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call' 
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call' 
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:621:in `call' 
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call' 
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:82:in `run_callbacks' 
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call' 
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call' 
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call' 
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call' 
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app' 
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call' 
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged' 
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged' 
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged' 
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call' 
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call' 
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call' 
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call' 
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/activesupport-4.1.1/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:26:in `call' 
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/actionpack-4.1.1/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call' 
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/heroku-deflater-0.5.3/lib/heroku-deflater/skip_binary.rb:19:in `call' 
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/deflater.rb:25:in `call' 
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/heroku-deflater-0.5.3/lib/heroku-deflater/serve_zipped_assets.rb:50:in `call' 
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call' 
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call' 
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/railties-4.1.1/lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call' 
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:576:in `process_client' 
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:670:in `worker_loop' 
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:525:in `spawn_missing_workers' 
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/lib/unicorn/http_server.rb:140:in `start' 
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/unicorn-4.8.3/bin/unicorn:126:in `<top (required)>' 
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/bin/unicorn:23:in `load' 
vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/bin/unicorn:23:in `<main>' 
Sent mail to wilson.lee86@gmail.com (148.7ms) 
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 1290ms
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set domain (not URL) as default url options host. Just try to remove `http://`

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: 'ballnow.herokuapp.com' }
```

Hope it helps.